# Getting Broadcomm Bluetooth to work

Tags: bluetooth, broadcom

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 and I'm trying to get Bluetooth to work.  There's a extra bit of firmware that has to be added to achieve that.  I actually was able to add that firmware, using the instructions at **https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware**.  But it seems that there's an extra step that's needed, and it's described on the same webpage that contains the firmware.  The problem I'm having is that the English is not very good and I can't understand it.  Here it is:

There may be incorrect naming between presented firmware name and name requested from Linux kernel. For example, system may request BCM4354A2-13d3-3485.hcd but actually this is BCM4356A2-13d3-3485.hcd. This is happens because incorrect naming in Linux kernel. Just rename file to name that need to kernel. Here quick naming convertion:
Original name   Requested by Linux  Notes
BCM4356A2   BCM4354A2

Could someone reword this for me?

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of [the incorrect names bit](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware#incorrect-names-for-devices), I would venture:

> There’s a typo in Linux kernels earlier than 5.8 that may result in the system requesting the wrong `.hcd` file. If you are using the BCM4356A2 chipset, you will need to rename (or copy) the correct `.hcd` file.

Given the size of the file, and given that more recent kernels will request a different file name, it might make sense to have two copies to cover both names.

1. Copy `BCM4356A2-13d3-3485.hcd` to `/lib/firmware/brcm`
2. Copy the file again:

   ```
   sudo cp /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM4356A2-13d3-3485.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM4354A2-13d3-3485.hcd
   ```

Hopefully this will result in a working device …

Comment: Where can I find BCM4356A2-13d3-3485.hcd?

Comment: These very long, very similar module names are very confusing!

Comment: It seems that the same problem arises in Windows 10, but the fix there is a little different!!

Comment: I tried to get Bluetooth working under Windows 10.  It doesn't work there either.  I wonder if those who have had some success have slightly different hardware.  Has Broadcomm supplied slightly different versions of the critical chip?